# Php list files in a directory and remove extention

Tags: php, list

I use this php code to retrieve the files stored in a directory .

```
if ($handle = opendir('FolderPath')) {

    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {

        if ($entry != "." && $entry != "..") {

            echo "$entry\n <br />" ; 
        }
    }

    closedir($handle);
}
```

This Directory only holds `PHP` files , how would i be able to remove the extension from the echoed results? example: ( `index.php` would become `index` )

Comment: Show what you have tried so far; others will gladly comment on your question based on your own code as opposed to writing a solution for you. Hint: regular expressions, substring matching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is by using [the `glob` function](http://php.net/glob):

```
foreach (glob('path/to/files/*.php') as $fileName) {
    //extension .php is guaranteed here
    echo substr($fileName, 0, -4), PHP_EOL;
}
```

The advantages of `glob` here is that you can do away with those pesky `readdir` and `opendir` calls. The only slight *"disatvantage"* is that the value of `$fileName` will contain the path, too. However, that's an easy fix (just add one line):

```
foreach (glob('path/to/files/*.php') as $fullName) {
    $fileName = explode('/', $fullName);
    echo substr(
        end($fileName),//the last value in the array is the file name
        0, -4),
    PHP_EOL;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

```
echo basename($entry, ".php") . "\n <br />" ;
```

Answer (score 1):

A quick way to do this is

```
<?php

 if ($handle = opendir('FolderPath')) {

    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {

      if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {

          $info = pathinfo($file);
          $file_name =  basename($file,'.'.$info['extension']);
          echo $file_name;
     }
    }

   closedir($handle);
```

?>

Answer (score 1):

```
$files = glob('path/to/files/*.*');
foreach($files as $file) {
  if (! is_dir($file)) {
    $file = pathinfo($file);
    echo "<br/>".$file['filename'];
  }
}
```

Use [pathinfo()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php)

Comment: Why not add the extension to the `glob` pattern? OP is only after .php files anyway

Answer (score 1):

```
$entry = substr($entry, 0, strlen($entry) - 4);
```

Note that this is a simple and quick solution which works perfect if you are 100% sure that your extension is in the form of *.xxx. However if you need a more flexible and safer solution regarding possible different extension lenghts, than this solution is not recommended.

Comment: what about files with an extension like `.o`, `.gz`, or `.html`, or binary files with no extension at all? there's no reason to assume a file will have an extension of 3 chars.

Comment: The question states clearly that the directory only holds PHP files.

Comment: That may be true now, but that's -IMHO- an unsafe assumption. using `glob` removes the need for `opendir` and `readdir`, _and_ guarantees to return an array only containing the files you're interested in

Comment: Thank you this did the trick , i do agree it is an unsafe assumption that it guarantees to return an array only containing the right files . However this folder is only used to store generated PHP files .

Comment: @user1443063: I'm sorry for asking, but if you agree with the statement that an assumption with regards to the extension is not the safest way to go, why then mark this answer as accepted. Other answers suggested using a better tool (`glob` is better in this case than `opendir` + `readdir`) _and_ did not make such assumptions. IMHO, those answers are better answers for any future visitors looking for the best way to scan directories (SO aims to be a knowledge base for others, who might not read the answers that aren't marked as accepted)

Comment: I accepted this answer because this one made an easy edit for my particular problem and no other requirements were specified .
But again i agree with your point of view that others might not read the answers that aren't marked as accepted .

Comment: @user1443063: NP, just playing SO police today... This answer is perfectly acceptable in _your_ case, but SO being a community driven site, I just find that we have to think of others, too. That's all

Comment: In that case; In the future please avoid an extensive discussion here. Editing the question to provide a little note for the future visitor (as I've just did) would have been sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Elegant solution would be to use `$suffix` attribute of `DirectoryIterator::getBasename()` method. When provided, `$suffix` will be removed on each call. For known extension, you can use:

```php
foreach (new DirectoryIterator('/full/dir/path') as $file) {
  if ($file->isFile()) {
    print $file->getBasename('.php') . "\n";
  }
}
```

or this, as an universal solution:

```
foreach (new DirectoryIterator('/full/dir/path') as $file) {
  if ($file->isFile()) {
    print $file->getBasename($file->getExtension() ? '.' . $file->getExtension() : null) . "\n";
  }
}
```

PHP docs: http://php.net/manual/en/directoryiterator.getbasename.php